# Openlayers 3 turn off smooth scroll

Tags: scroll, openlayers-3

I currently have an Openlayers 3 integration with many updating features, these make the scrolling stutter, especially when the 'kinetic' movement (flick scroll) is used.  Is there a way to turn that smooth scrolling with inertia off so the user has to drag to move the map?

Removing the animation on zoom would help too.

I've been looking in the ol.animation area for these - is that the right place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kinetic can be turned off in the `ol.interaction.DragPan` interaction.  Removing the animation while zooming can be done by passing `duration: 0` to the `ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom`.

See a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9v6fd6as/1/

Here's the example source code:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
    dragPan: false,
    mouseWheelZoom: false
  }).extend([
    new ol.interaction.DragPan({kinetic: false}),
    new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom({duration: 0})
  ]),
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  I'll have to remember the .extend functionality - the OL 3 documentation needs a fair amount of work.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer from Alexandre Dube is correct for **older versions** of openlayers.

If you're using **OpenLayers 6+ with TypeScript**, this is how you can disable animated panning:

```js
import Interaction from "ol/interaction/Interaction";
import DragPan from "ol/interaction/DragPan";
import {defaults as defaultInteractions} from 'ol/interaction.js';
import {Kinetic} from "ol";
// ...

ngOnInit() {
    this.map = new Map({
      //...
      interactions: defaultInteractions({
        dragPan: false
      }).extend([new DragPan()]),
      //...
    });
}
```

Comment: Use `DragPan()` and not `DragPan({kinetic: new Kinetic(0, 0, 0)})` or you'll hit this issue: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14426